# Where am I losing lazyness?

Tags: clojure

I am attempting to program a lazy iterative prime sieve.

Each iteration of the sieve is represented by

```
[[primes] (candidates) {priority-map-of-multiples-of-primes}]
```

and I have a function, sieve-next-candidate-update, that merrily takes a sieve iteration, checks the next candidate, and updates all three components appropriately.

Used like this:

```
(take 3 (iterate sieve-next-candidate-update [[2] (range 3 13 2) (priority-map 2 2)]))
```

I get the results I expect:

```
([[2] (3 5 7 9 11) {2 2}]
 [[2 3] (5 7 9 11) {3 3, 2 4}]
 [[2 3 5] (7 9 11) {5 5, 2 6, 3 6}])
```

However, when I run it through a reduce to remove the iterations that do not find a new prime, it attempts to process the entire sequence however I define the initial candidates list (apparent infinite loop if I use iterate).

```
(take 3 
   (reduce (fn [old-primes-sieves new-sieve]
             (prn (str "reduce fn called with new sieve" new-sieve))
             (if (= (last (first (last old-primes-sieves))) ; I'm aware I don't want last in the final version
                    (last (first new-sieve)))
               old-primes-sieves
               (conj old-primes-sieves new-sieve)))
           []
           (iterate sieve-next-candidate-update [[2] (range 3 13 2) (priority-map 2 2)])))
```

outputs

```
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2] (3 5 7 9 11) {2 2}]"
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2 3] (5 7 9 11) {3 3, 2 4}]"
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2 3 5] (7 9 11) {5 5, 2 6, 3 6}]"
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2 3 5 7] (9 11) {7 7, 2 8, 3 9, 5 10}]"
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2 3 5 7] (11) {3 9, 2 10, 5 10, 7 14}]"
"reduce fn called with new sieve[[2 3 5 7 11] nil {11 11, 2 12, 3 12, 7 14, 5 15}]"
```

and then throws a NullPointerException in this limited case.

Where am I losing lazyness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) is not lazy - it will try to iterate whole infinite sequence `(iterate sieve-next-candidate-update [[2] (range 3 13 2) (priority-map 2 2)])`. You can use [reductions](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions) instead.

By the way, nice example of efficient infinite prime numbers sequence can be found in [clojure.contrib](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib) [here](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/78ee9b3e64c5ac6082fb223fc79292175e8e4f0c/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/lazy_seqs.clj#L66).